# OpenGL illuminating opposite faces with the same normal

Tags: opengl

Using OpenGL shaders, I want to render a solid cube using diffuse lighting. To do this, I compute the normal of each vertex, and then compute the dot product between this normal and the direction of the light. The problem with this is that each pair of flat surfaces on the cube has the same normal direction, and therefore the same lighting intensity. But if the light source is directly above the cube, then the top surface should be bright, and the bottom surface should be dim -- they should not be the same.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal on top of the cube should have the opposite direction than the one on the bottom. Due to this, the result of the dot product will be 1 for the upper side and -1 for the bottom plane. If you clamp the dot-product to the [0, 1] range, the bottom side will be dark.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. When I define the normal for each vertex, I take the cross product of two sides of the triangle which the vertex is part of. So how do I ensure that vertices on opposite faves have opposite normals? Do I have to manually set the direction of the normal? Or is it to do with in which order the cross product is taken?

Comment: This is given by the order of the cross products arguments. When all your triangles have the same winding order, then nothing special has to be done. Just calculate the normal for all of them in the same way.